# jQuery Mobile PhoneGap App flickers on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, load

I have a `jQuery Mobile` `PhoneGap` app that loads all of my pages fine, except for then my app starts up.
The application shows a screen that says Phone gap IPhone non-retina and then shows all of the pages I have created on one screen before my application starts. I load the stylesheets scripts and html body dynamically in a java script file.
Is this a problem that would be occurring on my end, phone gaps end, or JQM end? I will supply code if need be.
I am using `JQM 1.2.0` `JQuery 1.8` and `JQM 1.2.0 css`

The flicker happens between the splash page and my first page load.I use this javascript to load the pages into my index.html

javascript:

```
       $("body").load(remoteURL + "body.html?v="+getTimeStamp(),function()
       {
          loadPage();
       }
```

Comment: I figured out that the Phone gap IPhone non-retina that pops-up on start up is a splash screen but there still is a white flash or period of flashing between the splash screen and loading of the first page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It take some time, for all scripts to load and your page to set up. You can go to the Phonegap.plist and disable the **AutoHideSplashScreen** and hide the splash screen from javascript, once the page is fully loaded with:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: where can I find the Phonegap.plist?

Comment: If you are using Cordova you should look for Cordova.plist (it was renamed).